# How can I block all the pages of the website except several ones?

Tags: windows-7

I want to block all the pages of the website except several ones. Tried putting something like "127.0.0.1 website.com/page.html" to "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts". It doesn't work. Seems like in this way you can block only the whole website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/hosts`, like DNS, is for hostname resolution - it works at a lower level than HTTP, and only deals with hosts and IP addresses.

To block websites partially, you could try a HTTP proxy with filtering capabilities - Privoxy or maybe even Squid. There also are [specialized filtering proxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-control_software).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome allows you to block all websites with exceptions in the registry. Refer to [this page](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#URLBlacklist) on how to edit the registry. Add all website by adding

```
"*"
```

in the blacklist, then make exceptions in the whitelist. If you need an easier way, go to the Google Web Store and install [TinyFilter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nlfgnnlnfbpcammlnibfkplpnbbbdeli).